# UIViewController is not opening in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

In my login page when I check the server output to see if it's "false" or not, if it's not false I add this code for moving to main viewcontroller class
but the below code is not working for me.

```
ViewController *main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"App"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
```

Please help me, my segue name is "App" and the main viewController id is also "App".

**CODE  used for sending url request  and getting server response**
stringValue contain my url

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: stringValue]];


    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    request.HTTPBody = myRequestData;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]




       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {


                               NSString * serverOutput= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                               NSLog(@"%@",serverOutput);

                               if(serverOutput!=NULL)
                               {

                                   if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"login"])
                                   {

                                       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"App" sender:self];
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                       NSError *jsonError = nil;
                                       id mylibrary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[serverOutput dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:0 error:&jsonError];


                                           NSDictionary *ratedBookList = [(NSDictionary*)mylibrary objectForKey:@"library"];

                                           [self saveMylibrary:ratedBookList];



                                   }

                                   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
                                   ViewController *main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"App"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];

                                   [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];


                                 }
                           } ];



    _alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait..."
                                            message:@"\n"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    spinner.center = CGPointMake(120, 75.5);
    [alertView addSubview:activityIndicator];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [alertView show];


}
```

Comment: are you sure that `@"App"` is the same string as in `Storyboard ID` in `Identity Inspector`? Can you post some error codes from NSLog?

Comment: YES that is same,I didnt get any error instead when i click login activity indicator will run and stop  .in the same page .but i can see my server output and respnse in log,all are showing that am loggged in  but my viewcontroller is not showing

Comment: Put breakpoint on code that you post in Question. Inspect what is going on. Post some screenshots that can give us some hints what is happening.

Comment: The code above mensioned to move to nxt viewcontroller is executing but view controller is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `StoryboardID` is correct and unique

Make sure the self.storyboard is having valid memory and it has the VC

eg

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
ViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"App"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: @mango : for me without checking it also worked.Edited the answer.Try it

Comment: what u mean by this Make sure the self.storyboard is having valid memory and it has the VC

Comment: the storyboard instance should be properly initialised and the nib of the viewcontroller should be in that storyboard